# PCRE exclude when word is in line

Tags: regex, pcre

I have regex `(#+.\d*\.\d)` to catch expression like #1.0 #-1.0 #1.5 ...
But I want to skip match if in line there is FCMP word

match this line

```
.text:00000000005A2F7C                 FMOV            D1, #1.0
```

skip this line

```
.text:00000000005A2F70                 FCMP            D0, #0.0
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `.*\bFCMP\b.*(*SKIP)(*F)|#-?\d*\.?\d+`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/GQgkX5/2)

Comment: Almost perfect! Thank you!
I forgot to mention that I need to skip lines with  #0
like
.text:00000000005A2F8C                 MOV             W18, #0

Comment: And how to add extra word to skip the line? For example FCMPE?

Comment: I figured out how to do it 
.*\b(FCMP|FCMPE)\b.*(*SKIP)(*F)|#-?\d*\.+?\d+

Thank you for your fast help!

Comment: So, the dot is a required char, I see, I posted the answer, please consider accepting.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
.*\bFCMP\b.*(*SKIP)(*F)|#-?\d*\.\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GQgkX5/3)

**Details**

- `.*\bFCMP\b.*(*SKIP)(*F)|` - a line (note the start and end of the line is matched with two `.*` patterns) containing a whole word `FCMP` (`\bFCMP\b`) that is matched and skipped (with `(*SKIP)(*F)`)
- `#-?\d*\.\d+` - matches `#`, an optional `-`, then 0 or more digits, a dot and then 1 or more digits.